# Is there an equivalent to a Java object in Python for memoization?

Tags: python, memoization

So I am trying to do memoization in a python **fibonacci(n)** function.

```
def fib(n, memo = [None] * (fibn+1)):
    if memo[n] != None: return memo[n]
    if n <= 2: return 1
    memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    return memo[n]
```

I am trying to find a way to store the solutions of values, which I already computed. My temporary solution to that is to make a list `memo = [None] * (fibn+1)` and if a new value is computed: `memo[n] = fib(n)`. The problem I have with this is that the list is mostly empty and is overall very inefficient. I want to go from this

`memo = [None, 1, None, 2, None, None, etc...]`

to something like this

```
memo = {
3: 2 
4: 3
7: 13
}
```

which is just like an object in Java.

Comment: It's a `dict`, and yes, that's typically what you would use to memoize a function.

Comment: You are currently just using a `list` to simulate (inefficiently, as you noticed) a `dict` with non-negative integer keys.

Comment: This sounds like you're thinking of *Javascript* objects. Java and Javascript are almost completely unrelated.

Comment: Also, the list is going to look like `[None, None, None, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...]`, not `[None, 1, None, 2, None, None, ...]`.

Comment: FWIW, a `list` would actually be the most efficient standard data structure for the memoization cache. The cache entries would *not* be sparse, unlike what the question implies. Starting at index 0 for `fib(0)`,  the entries are `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, the first three really are `None`.

Comment: @KellyBundy With an inefficient implementation, yes. Pre-filling the cache for the first entries instead avoids the (incorrect!) special case for n<=2.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah, you mean a different implementation. Yes, I actually [did that](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsIwEETv@Yo9ZrGVpF5EaH@k9FDpRgN2E5Z48OtjEgvObWYeM/GTnoEv1yg5b@TA@bvmDnbaA4wwmw7sgjcFRd4BwzTCi1jX/oirqj2vMRJvui30FuH0G@sHxAYKpbdwY2delIriOTXcGlMYF6QceAZZ@UF6MMfBn2PEnL8).

Answer (score 8):

Python provides decorators that can cache the results for you automatically in the `functools` module:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

A Python [Dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) can be used to store key-value pairs in this way (as chepner said in his comment on the question).

The `functools` module is also an option, but if you want to directly access the cache yourself you have to use a Dictionary.